# React: how to propagate state to enclosing parent

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, state

I have 2 classes to provide the modal-dialog functionality:

```
import React from 'react'
import Modal from 'react-modal'

export default class ModalBase extends React.Component {

  state = { show:false }

  handleOpen = opts => {
    this.setState( { ...opts, show:true } )
    console.info( 'ModalBase handleOpen', this.constructor.name, 'show', this.state.show )
  }

  handleClose = () => this.setState( { show:false } )

  render() {
    console.info( 'ModalBase render show', this.state.show )

    return <Modal isOpen={this.state.show} onRequestClose={this.handleClose} className="Modal" overlayClassName="Overlay">
      {this.props.children}
    </Modal>
  }
}
```

and

```
export default class InfoPopup extends ModalBase {
  
  state = { ...this.state, tech:{} }

  render() {
    console.info('InfoPopup render show', this.state.show)

    return ( 
      <ModalBase>
       <div/><div/>
      </ModalBase>
    )
  }
}
```

When I call `InfoPopup.handleOpen({a:42})`, the following shows up in the console:

```
ModalBase handleOpen InfoPopup show true
InfoPopup render show true 
ModalBase render show false
```

so, the ModalBase's state.show is not changed and hence the popup is not shown.

How shall I properly propagate the state to enclosing parent object?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

### Use composition instead of inheritance

From the React docs:

> React has a powerful composition model, and we recommend using composition instead of inheritance to reuse code between components.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

So `export default class InfoPopup extends ModalBase` is not advised.

### 1. Let `InfoPopup` render `ModalBase` but keep track of open/close state

You could turn it around and have a generic `BaseModal` component for modal styling that you pass props such as `title` and `content`. The `InfoPopup` keeps track of the opened/closed state. From the same React docs page:

```
function Dialog(props) {
  return (
    <FancyBorder color="blue">
      <h1 className="Dialog-title">
        {props.title}
      </h1>
      <p className="Dialog-message">
        {props.message}
      </p>
      {props.children}
    </FancyBorder>
  );
}

class SignUpDialog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSignUp = this.handleSignUp.bind(this);
    this.state = {login: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Dialog title="Mars Exploration Program"
              message="How should we refer to you?">
        <input value={this.state.login}
               onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <button onClick={this.handleSignUp}>
          Sign Me Up!
        </button>
      </Dialog>
    );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({login: e.target.value});
  }

  handleSignUp() {
    alert(`Welcome aboard, ${this.state.login}!`);
  }
}
```

### 2. Render `ModalBase` and pass the type of modal as prop

You could also always render `ModalBase` for an info, warning, error modal etc. Then you pass the type of modal as prop to `ModalBase`. `ModalBase` determines some specifics based on that type prop.

### 3. use a render prop

Described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Let `ModalBase` accept a function as children prop.

So in `InfoPopup`:

```
<ModalBase>
  {({ toggle }) => (
    <button onClick={toggle} />
  )}
</ModalBase>
```

And in `ModalBase`:

```
render() {
  return <Modal ...>{this.props.children({ toggle: this.openOrClose })}</Modal>
}
```

### 4. Pass a component to `ModalBase` to render when open

A bit of a variant on 2. You could also pass a component as prop to `ModalBase` that it should show when it's open.

```
<ModalBase
  modalContent={<InfoPopup />}
/>
```

Comment: 1. is my starting point and is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I want to keep `show` state in a parent/enclosing component

Comment: Yes :) so 2, 3 and 4 make that possible I think right?

Comment: no, it would only make code even more complicated comparing to the 1st naive implementation